# Image included via raw html not showing

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have

```
docs/_images/img.png
docs/conf.py
docs/index.rst
```

and in `index.rst`

```
.. raw:: html

    <img src="_images/img.png">
```

This won't display `img.png` or copy it to `docs/build/html/_images/img.png`. In full context I'm using `<img>` wrapped by other HTML tags for advanced functionality that can't be replicated with `.. image::` or `.. figure::`.

Workarounds?

Comment: Two options. Add the image to [`html_static_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_static_path). Or use `raw` for the wrappers around `image`, using the `image` directive to automatically copy the image file.

Comment: @StevePiercy So opt 1 every image would have to be added individually? And how: is `html_static_path = ['_static', '_images/img.png']` supposed to work? Doesn't for me but I've yet to reproduce minimally.

Comment: You could try adding the directory that contains the files to be copied into `_static` in the build directory. I don't know if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

In `conf.py`, get all files of interest in `_images/` and write them to an existing *and included* `.rst` as

```
.. image:: _images/img.png
  :height: 0px
  :width: 0px
```

This won't render them at all and will include them with Sphinx's native functionality, unlike direct file copy hacks, some of which have failed in ReadTheDocs builds for me. Note "write to `.rst`" means use `.. include` (to not modify the `.rst` itself with each rerun).

---

##### Example `conf.py` script

This is for `docs/source` structure.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import textwrap  # standard library

# get directories
confdir = Path(__file__).parent        # docs/source
src_imgdir = Path(confdir, '_images')  # docs/source/_images

# get image paths & make .rst text
img_exts = ('.png', '.jpg', '.mp4', '.gif')
txt = ""
for file in src_imgdir.iterdir():
    if file.suffix in img_exts:
        txt += """
               .. image:: _images/{}
                 :height: 0px
                 :width: 0px
               """.format(file.name)
# unindent multiline string
txt = textwrap.dedent(txt)

# make a .txt to be `.. include`-ed
with open('silent_image_includes.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt)
```

and add e.g. at end of `index.rst`

```
.. include:: silent_image_includes.txt
```

Comment: if you mark this new page or `:orphan:` it does not need to be listed in index page